# How to evaluate this limit involving a triple integral?

Tags: integration, limits

How to evaluate this limit involving a triple integral?

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{x^n(1-x)^ny^n(1-y)^nz^n(1-z)^n}{[1-(1-xy)z]^{n+1}}d x dydz}
\end{align*}

It's easy to see that
\begin{align*}
&\sqrt[n]{\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{x^n(1-x)^ny^n(1-y)^nz^n(1-z)^n}{[1-(1-xy)z]^{n+1}}d xd yd z}\\
\leqslant &
\sqrt[n]{\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{x^n(1-x)^ny^n(1-y)^nz^n(1-z)^n}{[1-(1-xy)][1-z]^{n}}d xd yd z}\\
\leqslant &
\sqrt[n]{\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1{x^{n-1}(1-x)^ny^{n-1}(1-y)^nz^n(1-z)^n}d xd yd z}\\
=&\sqrt[n]{\int_0^1x^{n-1}(1-x)^nd x\int_0^1y^{n-1}(1-y)^nd y\int_0^1{z^n}d z}
\to \frac{1}{4}\cdot \frac14\cdot 1=\frac1{16},n\to \infty \\
&~(\text{By using Stirling's formula})
\end{align*}

But I'm not sure $\frac1{16}$ is the right answer.How to do it ?Can anyone afford some help?Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you have only shown that the limit is *no greater than* $1/16$. It could be smaller (say, $0$).

Comment: @MPW It is less than $1/16$ by a factor of $2.12$. See my answer ;)

Comment: @mbfkk where did you get this problem?

Answer (score 2):

*This is not an answer.*

Just out of curiosity, I computed numerically the value of 
$$
f_n=\sqrt[n]{\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{x^n\,(1-x)^n\,y^n\,(1-y)^n\,z^n\,(1-z)^n}{[1-(1-xy)z]^{n+1}}\,dx\, dy\,dz}
$$ and obtained the following results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & f_n \\
 5 & 0.0453783835 \\
 10 & 0.0568806730 \\
 15 & 0.0631494275 \\
 20 & 0.0672030029 \\
 25 & 0.0700772984 \\
 30 & 0.0722394764 \\
 35 & 0.0739346466 \\
 40 & 0.0753039687 \\
 45 & 0.0764360143 \\
 50 & 0.0773910546
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathbb D$ be the unit cube in $\mathbb R^3$ (a cube with volume $1$ whose corner is at the origin) and define $g:\mathbb D\to\mathbb R$ as:
$$g(\mathbf x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_1x_2x_3(1-x_1)(1-x_2)(1-x_3)}{(1-x_3+x_1 x_2 x_3)^{1+\frac 1n}}$$
If we define $f:\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R$ as
$$f(\mathbf x)=\begin{cases}g(\mathbf x)&\mathbf x\in\mathbb D\\0&\text{elsewhere}\end{cases}$$
then your limit is the definition of the infinity-norm of $f$:
$$\|f\|_\infty=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\int_V |f|^ndv\right)^{\frac 1n}$$
which, [if I am not mistaken](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/549632/), is equal to:
$$\|f\|_\infty=\sup\{|f(x)|:x\in\mathbb{R}^3\}$$
So we are left with calculating the suprimum of $g$ on $\mathbb D$, which occurs at:
$$(x_1,x_2,x_3)=\left(\sqrt{2}-1,\sqrt{2}-1,\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)\implies g(x)=17-12\sqrt{2}$$
**Edit-** The above values are obtained by running this code in Mathematica:

```
Maximize[{x1 x2 x3(1-x1)(1-x2)(1-x3)/(1-x3+x1 x2 x3),0<x1<1 && 0<x2<1 && 0<x3<1},{x1,x2,x3}]
```

The formal way is to calculate the derivative of $g$ and see where it vanishes. Of course that would be tedious.

Comment: Why not simply define and consider $$g(x)=\frac{x_1x_2x_3(1-x_1)(1-x_2)(1-x_3)}{1-(1-x_1 x_2)x_3}\ ?$$

Comment: @Did I am not so familiar with real analysis. At first I wanted to do so, but I feared it might be wrong. Your suggestion made it clear that it was the right way

Comment: OK. You might want to add explanations about the computation of the maximum of $g$ at the end.

Comment: @Did Done that. Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: "The formal way is to calculate the derivative of g and see where it vanishes." This assumes that the maximum is in the interior of the domain, hence some more explanations are required here.

Comment: @Did That's why I used the word _tedious_

Comment: Hmmm... It seems that your "tedious" was referring to the computation of the gradient of $g$ and to the identification of the points where it is zero, not to the fact that this whole operation does not suffice to conclude when the maximum is on the boundary.

Comment: polfosol are you sure this is correct?Claude Leibovici has obtained a different numerical value

Comment: @UmbritaAndrei Yes I am sure. As far as I can see, Claude hasn't _obtained_ anything. And he said that himself at the beginning